# How to center a banner and keep margin?

Tags: html, css

This banner is centered but I still want a margin on the left. I want it to be indented after re-sizing the window so it looks better on lower resolutions and phones.

```
<div id="banner">
   <center>
      <a target="banner" href="index.html" >
        <img src="images/banner.jpg" border="0" alt="GamerZone Banner">
      </a>
   </center>
</div>
```

I would like to use css instead of html center as well. Thanks.
I wasn't sure how to do it really since I just started learning HTML a week ago. Could you possibly tell me what to try?

Comment: You currently don't have any margin. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: The image tag is not closed correctly

Comment: @AshReva: in XHTLML, yes true, in HTML5? no, its correct

Comment: @Mark thanks for info. I was not aware of it.

Comment: If it is html5, lose the `<center>` tag. Depricated!

Comment: wtf, no one suggesting jquery

Comment: @Ark I haven't even started learning about jquery yet lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add padding to the container instead e.g.

```
#banner{
     padding:0 20px;
}
#banner img{
     display:block;
     margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS:**

```
#banner{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center; /*centers horizontally*/
    line-height:300px; /*same as height and for centering vertically*/
}

<div id="banner">
 <a target="banner" href="index.html" title="some">
  <img src="images/banner.jpg" border="0" alt="GamerZone Banner">
 </a>
</div>
```

Hope this works. **check this jsfiddle:**http://jsfiddle.net/ACuKe/1/

Comment: That pushed everything to the right so it's all messed up now.

Comment: check the fiddle @user2132923

Answer (score 1):

simply give this style to achieve what you required,

```
div#banner
{
  margin:0 auto;
  height: 100px;    //your own height
  width: 100px;    //your own width
}
```

This will keep your div always in center irrespective of any screen resolution. see [here](http://jsbin.com/ofikaq/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="banner" style="text-align:center; margin:0 auto;">
<a target="banner" href="index.html" style="display:block; text-indent:30px;"><img src="images/banner.jpg" border="0" alt="GamerZone Banner"></a></div>
```

Set the margin property of the  element as "0 auto" (shorthand for "margin-top:0; margin-right:auto; margin:bottom:0; margin-left:auto;") plus "text-align:center".

Then you can give the  element a fixed "text-indent" (for single-line-content) or a fixed "margin-left".